# Changing color of list option when hovering a sub list

Tags: html, css, list, hover

I have a list, and when hovering over one of the options it displays a sub list. When I hover over an option on the second list, I want it to change the background color of the list item, that I had to hover over to get the second list.

```css
 #nav ul.topnav {
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     top: 10px;
     right: 425px;
    }
    
    #nav li.n {
     display: inline;
     float: left;
     width: 150px;
     padding: 10px;
    }
    
    #nav a.na {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px, 10px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;  
     font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif
    }
    
    #nav a.na:hover {
     color: #2E9AFE;
     background: #848481;
    }
    
    #nav ul.innernav {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
    }
    
    #nav li.n:hover ul.innernav {
     display: block;
     list-style-type: none;
     text-align: center;
     background: #A4A4A4;
     top: 40px;
     width: 110px;
    }
    
    #nav li.drop {
     position: relative;
     left: -45px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 150px;
    }
    
    #nav li.drop:hover {
     color: #2E9AFE;
     background: #848484;
    }
    
    #nav li.drop:hover a.na {
     background: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
      <li class="n">
       <a class="na" href="index.html">Blog</a>
       <ul class="innernav">
        <li class="drop">
         Dungeons and Dragons
        </li>
        <li class="drop">
         Video Games
        </li>
        <li class="drop">
         Movies/T.V
        </li>
        <li class="drop">
         News
        </li>
        <li class="drop">
         Science
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="n">
       <a class="na" href="about.html">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="n">
       <a class="na" href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
```

I thought

```
 #nav li.drop:hover a.na{
        background: #000000;
    }
```

Would get it to work

Comment: This is possible to do if it also changes the background of the top menu list on hovering that as well. If you don't want that, you'd need to use js/jquery then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because there is no parent selector in CSS. You could accomplish this using jQuery:

```
$("li.drop").hover(function(){
    $(this).closest("ul.innernav").siblings("a.na").css({"background":"red"}); 
    
},function(){
    $(this).closest("ul.innernav").siblings("a.na").css({"background":"transparent"}); 
});
```

This will find only the `a` of the sub menu and change the color

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/a287w882/1/)

## **OR**

Since everything is contained within `li.n` you could change the background of `a` on hover anytime you're in that element like so:

```
#nav li.n:hover a{
   background: red;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/a287w882/2/)

**UPDATE**

If you only want that one `li` to hover you can use `nth-of-type`

```
li.n:nth-of-type(1):hover a{
   background: red;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/a287w882/3/)

Comment: @Kalkrin added an alternative CSS example too

Comment: Ok this is looking good, I just don't want it to do that for the other two, so I will play with the classes a little bit.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you :D how do you know about "nth-of-type" I have never heard of it, could you link something that explains it?

Comment: its a CSS3 selector and its very useful: [http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this is only possible using the Javascript library JQuery.

Here is some JQuery that you can use and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj68auhc/) with the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".n li.drop").on("mouseover", function() {
        $("a.na").css("background", "#000000");    
    });
    $(".n li.drop").on("mouseout", function() {
        $("a.na").css("background", "#FFFFFF");    
    });
});
```

Also you didn't have a `#nav` element, so I replaced that with `.n`:

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the `<a>` link in the parent `<li>` of a sub menu to maintain it's hover state while you are hovering on one of it's child items - You don't need JS for this.
You can simply do a `li:hover` declaration in CSS to achieve it.

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/thePav/n01c0e2h/

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for! I just need to play with the classes a little bit because I don't want it to do that for the other parent list options.